# Ext JS 3.4: How to get form's request url after GET post

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a form in Ext JS 3.4:

```
        function exportIE() {
            //var date = new Date();
            //Ext.getCmp('resolvedID').setValue(date);
            // create the window on the first click and reuse on subsequent
            // clicks
            if (!winie) {
                winie = new Ext.Window(
                        {
                            // applyTo:'hello-win',
                            id : 'ie-cl',
                            layout : 'fit',
                            width : 400,
                            height : 100,
                            closeAction : 'hide',
                            plain : true,
                            title : 'Export Individual User Issues to Excel',
                            items : ieform,
                            buttons : [
                                    {
                                        text : 'Submit',
                                        handler : function() {
                                            var url = "$baseUrl/plugins/servlet/timesheet/exportindividualtoexcel?project=$project&month=$month&year=$year&filtered=true";                                               
                                            if(ieform.getForm().isValid()){
                                            winie.hide();
                                            ieform
                                                    .getForm()
                                                    .submit(
                                                            {
                                                                waitMsg : 'Sending...',
                                                                url : url,
                                                                method: 'GET',
                                                                success : function(
                                                                        response,
                                                                        options) {
                                                                    quickcreateform
                                                                            .getForm()
                                                                            .reset();
                                                                    /*Ext.MessageBox
                                                                    .alert(
                                                                            'Success',
                                                                            'Issue resloved');*/
                                                                    //eraseCookie('timeout');
                                                                    //eraseCookie('counter');
                                                                    store.reload();
                                                                    //storechart.loadData();
                                                                    storechart.reload();
                                                                },
                                                                failure : function(
                                                                        response,
                                                                        options) {
                                                                    /*Ext.MessageBox
                                                                            .alert(
                                                                                    'Error',
                                                                                    'Unable to create issue');*/
                                                                    //eraseCookie('timeout');
                                                                    //eraseCookie('counter');
                                                                    quickcreateform
                                                                            .getForm()
                                                                            .reset();
                                                                    store.reload();
                                                                    //storechart.loadData();
                                                                    storechart.reload();

                                                                }
                                                            });
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }, {
                                        text : 'Close',
                                        handler : function() {
                                            ieform.getForm().reset();
                                            //store.reload();
                                            winie.hide();
                                        }
                                    } ]
                        });
            }
            winie.show(this);
        }
```

So this form is made for download Apache POI MS Excel file so I need to add this to forms submit success function:

```
 document.location = request.url;
```

So how to I do it?

So I need that URL what Submit GET URL is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based to above I made this code and now it works:

```
var users = Ext.getCmp('select-user-combo').getValue();

document.location = options.getUrl(false)+"&users="+users;
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL used for submitting the form is available from the [`Ext.form.Action`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Action) used in the submission:

```
action.getUrl(true)
```

where the `true` argument indicates that it is a GET case and therefore the form parameters need to be appended to the URL. See the [source code](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/source/Action.html) for details.

The `action` object is available from the `success` function as its second argument (as the [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.BasicForm-method-submit) says):

```
success: function(form, action) {

}
```

(Note that your code is naming the arguments `response` and `options` for some reason).

So, you just take the second argument from the success function and call `getUrl(true)` on it.

Comment: And this code gets params from form. So URL must be $baseUrl/plugins/servlet/timesheet/exportindividualtoexcel?project=$project&month=$month&year=$year&filtered=true&users=username not $baseUrl/plugins/servlet/timesheet/exportindividualtoexcel?project=$project&month=$month&year=$year&filtered=true

Comment: I noticed also that form submit on my code goes to failure.

Comment: This answerd does not work, get params from form missing for URL.

Comment: Post a fiddle on fiddle.sencha.com, I'll have a look.